# Security Tab missing on internet explorer

Tags: security, group-policy, internet-explorer

I have a windows 2003 SBS domain, which I administrate to the best of my limited abilities. I need to install an active X-control for which I must change settings in internet explorer. It surfaced that on all computers in the domain the Security tab in internet explorer (8) is disabled. I vaguely remember to have done this once while trying to restrict access to certain internet sites through group policies (and failed). I am afraid I did not create and link a new group policy for that, but that I changed an exisiting one (if it was me that did it, it may be that some update caused it). I am unable now to locate the setting responsible for blocking the security tab. What is the easiest way to reverse it?

Comment: I've faced a similar issue, and this article helped me. May help you too... http://www.grishbi.com/2015/03/unable-to-change-ie-zone-security-settings/

Answer (score 2):

Run the Group Policy Results wizard in the GPMC for one of the affected computers and users. This will show you which GPO's are being applied and the settings that are being applied by those GPO's.

Answer (score 0):

yes, run rsop.msc  then go through the polices until you find a policy which is setting IE settings. your looking for user configuration\administrative templates\windows components\internet explorer\internet control panel. The setting is "disable the security page" set it to disabled or not configured.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bunch of settings in a "master" GPO, check under Administrative Templates / Windows Components / Internet Explorer / Internet Control Panel.

There is a setting there called Disable the Security Page that might be what you're looking for.